# Add GTFS to Network Dataset; stop_times.txt data is not transfering

Tags: arcgis-desktop, general-transit-feed-specification

I am using the [Add GTFS to Network Dataset toolbox from ArcGIS.com](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=0fa52a75d9ba4abcad6b88bb6285fae1) with a publicly available feed.

I successfully imported this feed once using the tools.

however, when I am trying to repeat the process, the stop_times table in the GTFS.sql table is empty, although the fields were loaded.

Any advice on how to correct this behavior?

Comment: Does the feed include all the fields of [`stop_times.txt`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Transit_Feed_Specification#stop_times)?